# laravel - middleware 'auth:sanctum' always fails

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-10, sanctum

I used laravel 10 to make a login API and it works and returns a token.

This a sample of returned tokens: 17|TlLRhxxWLRwP9fElWFNNg63XI99WFMEi3fSiZ61w1909a9d1

and this is the controller action:

```
public function loginApi(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt($data)) {
            $user = User::where('username', $data['username'])->first();
            $token = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;
            return $token;
        }
        return response('Invalid values!', 400);
    }
```

After that I made a new API route to create posts;
this is the route in api.php:

```
Route::post('/create-post', [PostController::class, 'insertApi'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);
```

but when I try to send the request, it always kicks me back to home page which means authorization fails.

I used "postman" and "insomnia" to send the requests
and in **authorization tab** clicked the **Bearer Token** and **pasted the token** for authorization,
but as I said, it kicks me back to home page...

request header:

[image]

response header:

[image]

Could someone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: what's your full POST request look like including the headers for that create-post end-point

Comment: this is what i send:
{
 "title": "New post with api",
 "body": "This post was created with OurApp's API."
}

Comment: Im more interested in the entire header and url not the body, post it on your question even just screenshot the request and response you get, including headers of both

Comment: i put the images

Comment: you need to add `Accept: application/json` in your request headers as stated in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication), make sure to follow whats written in the docs

Comment: i think this is not the problem,
because the request doesn't even gets to the action because the "auth:sanctum" middleware doesn't let it.

Comment: there are multiple possible reason that an authenticated request would fail, including the correct headers which is important as clearly stated in the documentation

Comment: the fact that your request is being redirected, it means you need to add that `accept` header

Comment: i added Accept: application/json but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I think you never properly follow the guide on how to enable api authentication, there are multiple steps you need to do  like adding correct headers and enable the sanctum middleware, its all written on that link I sent